# Find X-Window Name

Tags: 12.10, gnome, xorg, keyboard

I am using a script called SendKeys (https://github.com/kyoto/sendkeys) which I want to use to send keyboard strokes to Skype.

I am able to get SendKeys to works perfectly with pluma (a text editor) and Google Chrome.

Send Keys works by sending keys to the name of an X-window, e.g.:

```
bash sendkey.sh 'Google Chrome' Control+v
```

I can send keys to Google Chrome by supplying the window 'Google Chrome' or 'Chrome' and for Pluma 'pluma' (lower case.) However I am not able to send anything to Skype. I do not know if this is because of a compatability issue or because I can't find out the name of the window.

Can anyone suggest how you determine the name of a x-window?

Or failing that suggest another way I may be able to send keyboard strokes to Skype.

Answer (score 6):

If you are unable to click on the window you want, you can use:

```
xwininfo -root -children
```

or

```
xlsclients
```

Those [should list all windows open](https://superuser.com/questions/176754/get-a-list-of-open-windows-in-linux/176761#176761) by their names. The first one worked better for me.

Answer (score 4):

The program `xwininfo` will do what you want.

Run `xwininfo` from the command line; the cursor will become a cross,click on the window you want to explore and a wealth of info will be reported.